# Insecure download blocked with TestCafe

Tags: testing, automation, ui-automation, testcafe, javascript-automation

I am trying to download an excel file with TestCafe. I am getting a popup with **Insecure download blocked** and the file is not getting downloaded. I am able to download files multiple times manually, but only with TestCafe automation facing the issue.

[image]

I have tried the below things so far.

- Setting Insecure Content Permission for Google Chrome.
- Tried running the test with flags --allow-running-insecure-content --disable-web-security --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=* --disable-features=InsecureDownloadWarnings

versions:

- Google chrome: **122.0.6261.128 (Official Build) (arm64)**
- TestCafe:**3.3.0**

Comment: Hello,
Please create a ticket using this [template](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TYPE%3A+bug&template=bug_report.yaml) and also share a [Minimal Working Example](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402636/faq/general-info?search#how-to-create-a-minimal-working-example-when-you-submit-an-issue) in that ticket so that the TestCafe team can research the issue and help you.